# How to extract substrings from strings

Tags: php, preg-match

So if I have this string

```
Offer ends 25 Dec 7:00pm CET -75% 27,99$ 6,99$ You're receiving
```

How would I capture the various datapoints reliably? So that it would work even if the dates/times/percentages changes.

What I want it to look like is basically:

```
$Percent: 75
$1: 27.99
$2. 6.99
$Ends: 25 Dec 7.00pm CET (capture everything between "Offer ends" and -**%)
```

Can anyone help me on the way to achiving this? All the numbers/dates can change, PM can turn to AM and CET can turn to CEST etc. I'm not sure how to reliably save it in all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array from your string and than use the array to get the data you need:

```
<?php

$string  = "Offer ends 25 Dec 7:00pm CET -75% 27,99$ 6,99$ You're receiving";

//make an array
$array = explode(" ", $string);

//to see which element of the array you need you can just print it.
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

//output the data
echo "Percentage: " . $array[6]. "<br>";
echo "1: " . $array[7]. "<br>";
echo "2: " . $array[8]. "<br>";
echo "Ends: ". $array[2] . " " . $array[3] . " " . $array[4]. "<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example with regular expressions and preg_match:

```
<?php

// Your data
$subject = "Offer ends 25 Dec 7:00pm CET -75% 27,99$ 6,99$ You're receiving";

// The pattern (note the use of groups in regexp with brackets)
$pattern = '/(\d{1,2} [a-z]{3} \d{1,2}:\d{2}[a-z]{2} [a-z]{3}) (\-?[0-9]{1,2}\%) (\d+,\d{2,}\$) (\d+,\d{2,}\$)/i';
$matches = [];
preg_match ( $pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);

$Percent = $matches[2];
$price_one = $matches[3];
$price_two = $matches[4];
$Ends = $matches[1];

?>
```

You can use this website to test / learn more about regex: https://regex101.com/